# SQL lagging issues

Tags: php, sql, pdo

ok when i run this sql along with a bunch of php coding it seems to take awhile to load. And i run the sql through the database sql part and it takes roughly 5 to 6 seconds to load. And if i add anything else to it, i get the gateway timeout cause it is to long. would like to know if there is a easier way to make this load quicker or shorten the sql code?

```
} elseif ($_GET['page'] == "newwartab") {
$servername = $config['sqlserver'];
$dbname = $config['sqldb'];
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname",     $config['sqluser'], $config['sqlpass']);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);//error_reporting(E_ALL);
//error_reporting(E_ALL);

$condition="`stats`.`name`=`chains`.`name` AND `chains`.`tag` IN ('Age Approved', 'SR-AaA', 'Sweet Revenge', 'SR-AaA-LH', 'SR-AaA-LH Slayer Squad', 'Against All Authority', 'Black Sails', 'DEMK', 'Loser')";
if ($login==0) { die(); }
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT `stats`.`spy` from `stats` WHERE `stats`.`name`='$user' LIMIT 1");
$query->execute();
$spy = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//$spy = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$spy = $spy['spy'];
$condition=$condition." AND `stats`.`sentry` <= ".$spy*2.2;
?>

$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT `stats`.`name`, `stats`.`active`, `stats`.`id`, `stats`.`sentry`, `stats`.`spy`, `stats`.`rank`, `stats`.`maxed`, `chains`.`name`, `chains`.`tag`, ((`stats`.`bpm`*1000000)+(`stats`.`ch`*450000)+(`stats`.`is`*1000000)+(`stats`.`ds`*200000)+(`stats`.`nun`*1000000)+(`stats`.`lt`*1000000)+(`stats`.`key`*600000)+(`stats`.`dog`*250000)) AS `tvalue` FROM `stats`, `chains` WHERE ".$condition." ORDER BY `tvalue` DESC LIMIT :start_from, :items_per_page");
$query->bindParam(':start_from', $start_from);
$query->bindParam(':items_per_page', $items_per_page);
while ($results = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){//end here and the rest is just echo's}
```

I left out the php cause i dont think that its the problem cause it loads fine without the sql.

Comment: Tag with the SQL Server that you're using, please.

Comment: Perhaps do it with `cron` or use `ajax`?

Comment: Have you added indexes to your table?

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` to ensure you're making use of your indexes.

Comment: Many possibilities here - what are the where clauses in $conditions? Are those where clauses able to leverage indexes? How many records are in this table? How many items in the result set are doing the extra math? A good place to start may be reading about the sql EXPLAIN command.

Comment: The use of `$condition` in your query string is a code smell -- there's nothing being bound there, it's likely a point of SQL injection.

Comment: ok ill paste the $condition with the above

Comment: Are you indexing?

Comment: You're using prepare() but you're still building the SQL with concatenation: `WHERE stats.name='$user'`

Comment: i dont think it is indexing. from either the stats table or the chains table. btw its pulling from 2 tables if ya didnt notice that before. but if i have it to index, is there a certain column i have to index or the whole table itself

Comment: MySQL returned an empty result set i tried to do index on the stats table and it gave that. im faily new to some of this with using my own database. so some things might need explained

Comment: I'm currently employed at a location that has firewall issues.  If I use SQL developer (oracle) that already has established it's connection to run a query I get a 2 second run time.  When I run a statement where I have to create the connection at runtime, the firewall interferes and it returns in around 40 seconds.  Any chance something outside of the SQL code is at play here?